# Can someone help me with this for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am a newbie to Matlab.Still trying to learn the syntax and everything.I have a large data matrix D.I am trying to remove part of the large matrix and make small matrices.I am searching the 3 columns and returning matrices which contain the numbers in the 3 columns.

```
BPI20 = D(D(:,1) == 0 &D(:,2)==0 &D(:,6)==20,:);
BPI21 = D(D(:,1) == 0 &D(:,2)==0 &D(:,6)==21,:);
BPI22 = D(D(:,1) == 0 &D(:,2)==0 &D(:,6)==22,:);
BPI23 = D(D(:,1) == 0 &D(:,2)==0 &D(:,6)==23,:);
BPI24 = D(D(:,1) == 0 &D(:,2)==0 &D(:,6)==24,:);
```

I want to write a for loop for the above code where the value of the variable BPI should also increase
Thank you

Comment: What does `D(:,6` look like? `1:24`?

Comment: D(:,6)=1:24.It is 1 for a certain number of rows and increments by 1

Comment: and what should be in `BPI18` or `BPI{18}` if `D(18,1)~=0 or D(18,2)~=0`? zeros? NaNs? empty? What do you want to do with it aftwerwards? Because you could potentially just simplify all your code above to: `BPI = D(D(:,1)==0 & D(:,2)==0)`

Comment: But I want separate matrices for BPI 20 to BPI 24.So I want to write for loop for the code above

Comment: ok, then use the loop in my solution and use `BPI{1}`, `BPI{2}`, etc instead of `BPI1`, `BPI2`, etc. Can you still tell us what you want to do with the resulting data? You know some `BPI{ii}` will be empty right? If `D(ii,1) == 0 &D(ii,2)==0` is not satisfied, `BPI{ii}` will be empty!! That's not due to my code, it's also present in the code in your question..

Comment: Each of BPI 1 should contain D(:,1)=0 ,BPI 2 should contain D(:,1)=1 and so on.D(:,2) should remain equal to 0.

Comment: maxHead =6;
for ii=1:maxHead
    BPI{ii} = M(M(:,1)==ii & M(:,2)==0 , :);
end

Comment: I used the loop above I am geeting the required answer just the problem is the results are stored in cell Head{1} to Head{7}.How do i convert them back to matrix because I want to perform operations on those.I tried using cell2mat function but it is giving out an error

Comment: `Head{1}` is just a matrix, `Head` is a cell array, `Head(1)` is a cell, `Head{1}` is the contents of that cell, being a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use such a name for `BPI` (ie names with an increment in the name itself), use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) instead:

```
col1is0 = D(:,1)==0;
col2is0 = D(:,2)==0;

maxBPI = 24;
BPI = cell(maxBPI,1);
for ii=1:maxBPI
    BPI{ii} = D(col1is0 & col2is0 & D(:,6)==ii, :);
end
```

see also [this post](http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/cssm/matlab-faq_4.html#evalcell)!

Comment: But will I have to convert the cell to matrix again?Because D is a matrix.

Comment: How can I access the cell arrays?And I need to do operations on the final BPI.So I will have to convert it to a matrix.I need to plot data from BPI.

Comment: my previous comment was wrong, or at least won't work always. click on the link in my post to learn how to work with cell arrays, you can see what's in a cell by using `BPI{2}` for example.

Comment: D(:,6)=1:24.It is 1 for a certain number of rows and increments by 1